# Connect WINCE6 device with jmeter

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter

I have a WINCE6 Device. Is there any plugin from jmeter to connect this device. Like TestQuest.. I want to do some Automation & Performance testing R&D on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all double check your project requirements as [Windows Embedded CE 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded_CE_6.0) extended support ended in 2018 and mainstream support was finished in 2013.

Second, it seems that you don't fully understand the concept of JMeter, it will not let you to conduct performance test of WinCE 6 device itself or applications running on it.

The only relationship between JMeter and mobile devices is that JMeter can represent from one to thousands of mobile devices by simulating their [network traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_traffic), for example if you have an application running on WinCE which sends network requests to some backend server you can use JMeter to represent many devices concurrently accessing the backend, so you will be testing the **backend**, not your application.

If this is your case you can configure your application to use JMeter as the proxy so when you start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) the traffic will go through JMeter and JMeter will capture it and generate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which you will be able to replay with the [increased load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users). Check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) article to learn more about the concept.

If you need to assess the client-side performance of an application - consider using [profiling tools for WinCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256291/code-profiling-performance-analysis-tools-for-windows-ce-mobile)